# Django rest framework return non-required field

Tags: django-rest-framework

In my serializer I have field that is set to non-required.

When I serialise model instance, this field is not in the output.

How can I include this filed in output?

```
class Client(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    profile_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='pictures/profile_photos')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")

class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(source='user.username')
    profile_photo = serializers.ImageField(source='details_sample.profile_photo', required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'profile_photo', 'phone')


@api_view(['GET'])
def get_user_info(request):

    client = Client.objects.get(user=request.user)
    serialized = ClientSerializer(client)

    return Response(serialized.data) # no profile_photo
```

Can you help me?

Comment: I don't know Django, but I think the source of the image is wrong. You say `details_sample.profile_photo` but there is no details_sample field in the Client instance. Try `source='profile_photo'`. It's just a guess anyway.

Comment: Change your serializer to source='profile_photo' and it shoud work.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    profile_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='pictures/profile_photos', null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")

class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(source='user.username')

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'profile_photo', 'phone')
```